# I can't add a node into an empty list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I stumbled upon a weird problem with adding two linked lists into a third one in Java, the first linked list "myList1", the second linked list "myList2" and the third one "myList3".

The combining method is supposed to to add the first LinkedList "myList1" then the second "myList2" into the third LinkedList "myList3", but I faced a problem with adding them to third list while it's empty, but if the third list has at least one element every thing goes smoothly.

The code:

```
Node current = myList1.head;            
while (current != null) {                                                                       
    Node newcurrent = myList3.head;
    int h1 = current.getData();                                  
    Node newNode = new Node(h1);
    if (newcurrent == null)     
        //the problem is with this code                                             
        newcurrent = newNode;                           
    else {                                     
        if (newcurrent.getLink() == null) {
            newNode.setLink(newcurrent.getLink());                                         
            newcurrent.setLink(newNode);                                      
        } else {                                        
            Node current11 = newcurrent;                                                
            while (current11.getLink() != null) {
                current11 = current11.getLink();
            }                       
            current11.setLink(newNode);                          
        }                                    
    }                                                           
    current = current.getLink();                            
}
```

The node is not added to the third LinkedList if the third list is empty, and I tried many other codes but it didn't work either, but if I entered at least one element to the third LinkedList the list is added normally.

other codes I tried :

```
newcurrent.setLink(newNode);
```

and

```
newNode = newcurrent; 
newcurrent = newNode;
```

and

```
newNode.setLink(newcurrent); 
newcurrent.setLink(newNode);
```

and

```
newNode.link = newcurrent; 
newcurrent.link = newNode;
```

Comment: remove blank lines from your code.

Comment: If you properly indent your code it makes it much easier to follow, maintain, and debug.

Comment: thank for editing the code, i'm sorry but it's my first time using this site

Comment: To reduce some of the complexity, you might consider writing a method which inserts all elements from one list into another. In other words, you can deal with only two lists at a time, if you want, rather than three. IMO, this would make debugging your code simpler.

Comment: @Code-Guru thank u, can u please show me how to do that ...

Comment: Are you able to enter the if loop for an empty list? Try doing a system.out.prinln to check.

Comment: @BasilBasaif 
                
private void InsertElements(LinkedList listSrc, LinkedList listDes){
//code to add elements from listSrc to listDes
}

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @AlastorMoody thank u, yes i already tried it it enters, but the node is not added !

Comment: @AlastorMoody yes, thank u , i'll try using a method for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this a bit, I think.  The links within the list are already there.  You only need to link `myList3.tail` to `myList1.head`, no need to loop through adding each node independently.  Since you don't look like you are storing a `tail`, you'll need to iterate to the end of `myList3` to find it.

```
if (myList3.head == null)
    myList3.head = myList1.head;
else {
    Node list3iter = myList3.head;
    while (list3iter.getLink() != null) {
        list3iter = list3iter.getLink();
    }
    list3iter.setLink(myList1.head);
    }
}
```

One further note, I find it painful to try to keep track of names like `current`, `current11`, `newcurrent`, etc.  They all mean just about the same thing to my brain.  If you're like me, a bit more descriptive naming might help you keep track of what your variables are meant to be doing here.

Comment: thank u, now it can add it to the list while myList3 is empty, but now when the myList3 has elements in it it enters an infinet loop

Comment: Okay, one of two things is occurring.  Probably, either, you created a [cyclic list](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Ouroboros-simple.svg/220px-Ouroboros-simple.svg.png), or you misunderstood the code.  The code in my answer replaced ALL of the the code in your question, not just the if/else block.

Comment: i replaced every thing, but not the while loop, should i replace it too, but i need to traverse all of myList1 so i can copy all the content in it to myList3

Comment: No, you don't.  That's my point.  The linked list is already there!  If I have two linked lists: `{n1->n2->n3}` and `{nA->nB->nC}`, then if I create the link from `n3` to `nA`, then the list is, without any other linkages made or work being done: `{n1->n2->n3->nA->nB->nC}`.  You don't need to add them all independently (and, in fact, would be incorrect to do so, unless you actively break the existing links as you go).

Comment: THANK U V.MUCH, actually it works perfectly right now, thank u for your help, i rally appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
Node newcurrent = myList3.head;
....
if (newcurrent == null)     
    //the problem is with this code                                             
    newcurrent = newNode;
```

Not sure why you have two lists, but the last line above is just assigning to local variable. Should it be as follows instead?

```
myList3.head = newNode
```

Comment: Thank u 
but it didn't work either, the problem is when the third list is empty but if it has at least one element inside of it, the first linked list is added smoothly.

Comment: What are the two lists `myList1` and `myList3` ?

Comment: i want to add myList1 into myList3